# Predicating Nested Array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nspredicate

Doing a project on addressbook kind of app. I need to predicate address book contacts, result looks like this

```
(
{
AddressKey =     (
);
Email =     (
);
"JobTitle_Name" = "";
"Organisation_Name" = "";
Phone =     (
            {
        phoneNumber = "+919502266633";
        "phone_type" = home;
    },
            {
        phoneNumber = 9703570333;
        "phone_type" = work;
    },
            {
        phoneNumber = 91234512345;
        "phone_type" = iPhone;
    },
            {
        phoneNumber = 91239123;
        "phone_type" = mobile;
    }
);
"first_name" = Raviraja;
imageKey = "";
"last_name" = "";
serialNumberKey = 53;
source = Device;
}
)
```

Need to predicate the array using phoneNumber key. I tried this one

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K == %@",@"phoneNumber",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];
        NSArray *array = [contactsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

but not working eventhough phone number is matching.

Help me out guys.

Comment: Note you can replace `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]` simply by `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key path is wrong, it should be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K == %@",@"Phone.phoneNumber", ...]
```

Comment: I love u bro.. so simple. Kind of regret, gimme ur mail ID, me nub teach me man